# Get firstname, lastname and email address from Facebook using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I have the below code in my Startup.Auth.cs file but I can't find a way to get the firstname and lastname from Facebook:

```
var facebookOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AppId = "",
    AppSecret = "",
    BackchannelHttpHandler = new FacebookBackChannelHandler(),
    UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?fields=id,email"
};

facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");
facebookOptions.Scope.Add("public_profile");

app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick example of how you can get the user information from Facebook in asp.net winforms. This example uses the [Facebook SDK for .Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Facebook/7.0.6).
This snippet logs in the user with Facebook and then gets the extra user info, but can also be used for just getting the extra profile data.

```
static string Facebook_Key = "yourAppID";
static string Facebook_Secret = "yourAppSecret";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //check if the user is returning from Facebook
    if (Request.QueryString["code"] != null)
    {
        FacebookClient fbc = new FacebookClient();

        //retreive the access token
        dynamic result = fbc.Post("oauth/access_token", new
        {
            client_id = Facebook_Key,
            client_secret = Facebook_Secret,
            redirect_uri = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri,
            code = Request.QueryString["code"].ToString()
        });

        fbc.AccessToken = result.access_token;

        //get the extra profile data
        dynamic user = fbc.Get("me?fields=first_name,last_name,id,email");

        //display the results
        FacebookLoginLabel.Text += user.id + "<br>";
        FacebookLoginLabel.Text += user.first_name + "<br>";
        FacebookLoginLabel.Text += user.last_name + "<br>";
        FacebookLoginLabel.Text += user.email + "<br>";

        //start the actual aspnet registration or login
        LoginOrRegisterUser();
    }
}

protected void FacebookLoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FacebookClient fbc = new FacebookClient();

    //start the Facebook login request
    var loginUrl = fbc.GetLoginUrl(new
    {
        client_id = Facebook_Key,
        redirect_uri = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri,
        response_type = "code",
        scope = "email"
    });

    //redirect the user to Facebook for authentication
    Response.Redirect(loginUrl.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

ASPX

```
<asp:Button ID="FacebookLoginButton" runat="server" Text="Log in with Facebook" OnClick="FacebookLoginButton_Click" />

<asp:Label ID="FacebookLoginLabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

Comment: How to get the public profile info? Adding ",public_profile" to the Fb.Get(...) part throws an exception ("accessing non existing field")

Comment: Did you check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions? Some field require extra permissions for your app. And it's been a while since i've worked with the FB login, but you may need to append `scope = "email"` for the permissions in the first request (not tested)