# how to add facebook auth in old ASPnet webforms site

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, owin

I'm currently working on a web project using webforms and trying to add facebook authentication to the site since it seemed very easy on the tutorials I found (generate the keys, set up the facebook app side, add them to the Startup.Auth.cs).

I managed to get authenticated, but I keep getting redirected to 
https://my123site.net/signin-facebook 
instead of 
https://my123site.net/RegisterExternalLogin 
which seems the correct page to go since I need to register the user.

I found many tutorials that appear to have different version of Owin than what I use, for example if I create a new website, I see it uses "OpenAuth" instead of Identity.

Is there a way to update my project to the latest version, so that I can easily add social media login? (the way they do here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jaq9m2og9mY )

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42880268/get-firstname-lastname-and-email-address-from-facebook-using-asp-net

Comment: Thanks!! I got it working by pure troubleshooting finally, will post how soon.